# internet explorer print

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, printing

How can I print a single dom element (such as table) or whole window dom object using java script in internet explorer, ff etc...?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot envoke printing from JS alone.  JS does not have the right permission to print directly from the browser.

Two appraches are:
1. Print CSS (a stylesheet that tells your browser how to create the file when printed)
2. Print link - a link that will only show the information needed for printing, will strip everything else out.